# Como adiciono esse contador de gastos ao meu tema WooCommerce?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Quero mais ou menos assim, fica elegante e prático.
Quem souber como faz ou outro jeito semelhante por favor ajudem. Obrigado!

[image: Tipo assim]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um plugin que faz isso: Woocommerce Menu Cart. Este é compatível com WooCommerce,
Easy Digital Downloads, Eshop, WP-Ecommerce eJigoshop.

Link para o plugin: [Woocommerce Menu Cart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-menu-bar-cart/)

Comment: valeu amigão!!!